# Azure SQL Parsing JSON from API pull in the stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, azure-functions

After migrating a system to Azure, some changes had to be made to accommodate the differences between on-site VS the cloud. I'm curious if there's a better way to do this, because I couldn't find any documentation to actually explain a step-by-step.

Simply put, I needed to be able to automate pulling data from an external API (not allowed with `sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint`) and then take the JSON response and use it to update the records in the appropriate database tables.

Here's what I have so far: the SQL to pull the response (I still need to parse the JSON response into the appropriate parameters):

```
DECLARE @ClaimID NVARCHAR(100) = 'ClaimIDHere';

DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'https://<API_URL_HERE>/ClaimID=' + @ClaimID + '&code=<AzureLogicAppCodeHere>';
DECLARE @ret INT, @response NVARCHAR(MAX);
EXEC @ret = sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint
             @url = @URL
           , @payload = NULL
           , @headers = @NULL
           , @method = 'GET'
           , @timeout = 30
           , @credential = NULL
           , @response = @response output;

SELECT @response
```

To which I get a successful response that I need to now parse out:

[image]

The Azure Function to get the JSON from the external API is pretty straightforward:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Net.Http"
#r "System.Data"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{  
    const string APIKey = "<API Key/Bearer Token Here>";    
    string ClaimID = req.Query["ClaimID"];
    log.LogInformation($"req ClaimID: {ClaimID}");
    string URL = $"https://<EXTERNAL API URL HERE>/{ClaimID}";

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", APIKey);    
    var response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
    
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(json) ? "Success!" : json;
            return new OkObjectResult(responseData);
}
```

And the last step is to parse the JSON in SQL so it can be assigned to variables (and the JSON values are case sensitive (IE:$.result.clientClaimNumber won't pull anything if the C for "client" is capitalized):

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@response)
     WITH (
              ID VARCHAR(100) '$.result.id',
              ClaimNumber INT '$.result.claimNumber',
              ClientClaimNumber VARCHAR(15) '$.result.clientClaimNumber'
          );
```

Am I missing anything? I have it set up so it lines up like:

1. Stored procedure pings the Azure Function and passes in the ID (as a query string parameter)
2. Azure function (containing bearer token for auth) pings the external API and passes along the query string parameter
3. Azure Function returns JSON response to the stored procedure
4. Stored procedure parses the JSON response, and assigns the appropriate values to the parameters for the Insert/Update stored procedure.

Comment: `Am I missing anything?` - firstly, please don't paste screenshots of code. Secondly, I don't see any database persistence in your C#.

Comment: Don't you mean Azure Function?  Not LogicApp?

Comment: @Skin Fixed... sorry.  Too much bouncing around different attempts to find a working solution.  

There's no database persistence in the C# because the sole purpose of the function is to retrieve a JSON response from the external (Non-azure hosted) API.  The SP connects to the function to get the data.  The function doesn't connect to the DB.

Comment: @jnelson You should **never, ever** do HTTP calls from a database; that is not what a database is intended for. To paraphrase Jurassic Park, "just because you can doesn't mean you should". Your function app should do the data retrieval, then call the insert/update sproc, which will also remove the need for the intermediate SQL step.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing anything?

I do the same way as you do, call the API from Azure functions as below:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Net.Http"
#r "System.Data"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    string id = req.Query["id"];
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    id = id ?? data?.id;
    string URL = $"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{id}";
    var client = new HttpClient(); 
    var response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(json) ? "Success!" : json;
            return new OkObjectResult(responseData);
}
```

and now call the stored procedure as below(similar code of and followed [Document](https://www.infoq.com/news/2022/11/azure-sql-rest-endpoint/):

```
   DECLARE @URI NVARCHAR(3000) = N'https://rith67.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=vbVma3O69JJ3NaX1lAzFu_5TN_g==';
DECLARE @rpro INT, @response NVARCHAR(MAX);
EXEC @rpro = sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint
             @url = @URI
           , @payload = NULL
           , @headers = @NULL
           , @method = 'GET'
           , @timeout = 20
           , @credential = NULL
           , @response = @response output;

SELECT @response
```

AFAIK, this is way to do it.